# Visual Studio 2010 RDLC upgrade

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reportviewer

I have .net 3.5 project containing some rdlc reports made in Visual Studio 2008. Opening the project with Visual Studio 2010 asks me to update the reports to RDLC 2008 format, at which point the reports dont work.

Seems there is an incompatibility.

Is there a good way to upgrade? Any workaround? I dont want to have to remake the reports, which means I have to continue to use Visual Studio 2008 to work on these projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ReportViewer 10.0 control that was just released and everything will work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Adding 2 cents to the answer above...The XML in the converted report looked fine but what's missing is the upgrade to the web.config. To get the proper values, I started a new report web  site in 2010 then compared the web.configs. I replaced all the items referencing "8.0" with the same items referencing "10.0" in the new site. I also added the "system.webServer" section which was missing from the old web.config. Finally, the new reportviewer control requires a scriptmanager, so I added that. After all of that the old reports worked fine in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you have something like that in order to render it an an ASP.NET page

```
LocalReport lr = new LocalReport();
lr.Render("PDF", deviceInfo,
                (a, b, c, d, e) =>
                {
                    return Response.OutputStream;
                }, out warn);
```

transform it into

```
LocalReport lr = new LocalReport();
var reportBytes = lr.Render("PDF", deviceInfo);
Response.BinaryWrite(reportBytes);
```